# memory alignment, gcc compiler on windows

Tags: c, gcc

does anyone ever met that `__attribute((packed))` does not recognized by the gcc compiler on windows platform? GCC version 6.3.0

```
typedef unsigned int   u32;
typedef          int   s32;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef          short s16;
typedef unsigned char  u8;
typedef          char  s8;

typedef struct{
    u16 limit;
    u32 base;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) gdt_register_t;
```

With `__attribute__ ((packed))` the size of `gdt_register_t` should be `6`, but in my environment it is `8`, i think the problem is that `__attribute__ ((packed))` didn't work.

Someone suggested me to use standard fixed size uint16_t, uint32_t, but the result is still `8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef unsigned int   u32;
typedef          int   s32;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef          short s16;
typedef unsigned char  u8;
typedef          char  s8;

typedef struct{
    u16 limit;
    u32 base;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) gdt_register_t;

size_t bar(void)
{
    return sizeof(gdt_register_t);
}

typedef struct{
    uint16_t limit;
    uint32_t base;
}__attribute__ ((packed)) gdt_register_t1;

size_t bar1(void)
{
    return sizeof(gdt_register_t1);
}
```

[image]

It seems like i should not easily use `gcc -c abc.c` to compile the file, need some other parameter?

Comment: 1. Do not use werid typedefs. Use standard fixes size types (int32_t, int16_t etc). unsigned int can be 8 or 4 or 2 bytes. You do not know.

Comment: Cant reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/eqzsohb63

Comment: Many many thanks for your effort, SALUTE! I tried these on my laptop, the result is both 8 bytes.

Comment: I tried it on my laptop and it's 6 not 8 using GCC compiler

Comment: may i know which instruction you used to compile your source file?

Comment: hey guys, i tried it on linux, and i got what i want, it's both with 6 bytes. I think it's highly possible a bug of os system

Comment: @hfieA the struct is compiled by the compiler. It has nothing to do with the OS. And why do you use such an ancient GCC version which may have bugs? The current one is 12.x

Comment: in the first paragraph you've used `__attribute((packed))` instead of the correct one `__attribute__ ((packed))`. Do you really have that typo when compiling on Windows?

Comment: @phuclv `__attribute((packed))` was typing error. You are right, i am nowing using the latest version, have the right result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your primary problem, but it's such a major thing I think it needs to be addressed properly.

You're using:

```
typedef int s32;
```

And this is wrong on so many levels. An `int` is not guaranteed to be 32bit. It's actually not even guaranteed to be at least that size. You're not only making a false promise which can be the root of future bugs, you're also skipping using the types that does exist for this purpose. Never EVER use that typedef.

If you want a 32 bit signed integer, then use `int32_t`. If you really want, you also have the alternatives `int_fast32_t` and `int_least32_t`, but those are not very common. There also exists unsigned versions and other sizes.

Apart from that, I don't know why it gives you the size 8. I tried your code and got the result 6. https://onlinegdb.com/2bCZM7AUZ

I guess you could try using `__attribute__((packed, aligned(X)))` where `X` is the alignment. Try to set it to 1 or 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i also tried to use int32_t or int16_t, but it still doesn't work. I would try to compile my source code under linux, see what gonna change.

Comment: hey, i tried it on linux, and i got what i want, it's both with 6 bytes. I think it's highly possible a bug of os system

Comment: I upgraded the version of my GCC, and it's now works in the right way. Thanks!